# Unir duas listas c#

Tags: c#, linq

Tenho 2 listas e gostaria de uni-las em uma unica para que sejam listadas.

Criei duas listas porque ambas apresentam condições diferentes da consulta e não consegui relaciona-las em uma unica lista. Segue o código:

```
UnitOfWork unitAux = new UnitOfWork();

List<VW_PARCEIROSOFERTAS> bdofertasPrazo = new List<VW_PARCEIROSOFERTAS>();
List<VW_PARCEIROSOFERTAS> bdofertasValor= new List<VW_PARCEIROSOFERTAS>();

var dePrazo = System.Convert.ToDecimal(Prazo);
var deValor = System.Convert.ToDecimal(Valor);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Prazo.ToString()) && dePrazo > 0)

    bdofertasPrazo = unitAux.Vw_ParceirosOfertas.ConsultaOfertaPorProduto(_empresaAtiva, Produto)
                .Where(q => q.PRAZOINICIAL <= dePrazo && q.PRAZOFINAL >= dePrazo && q.TIPOFAIXAPRECO == "P").ToList();

//.Where(q => q.PRAZOINICIAL >= dePrazo && q.PRAZOFINAL <= dePrazo && q.TIPOFAIXAPRECO == "P").ToList();             

{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Valor.ToString()) && deValor > 0)
        bdofertasValor = unitAux.Vw_ParceirosOfertas.ConsultaOfertaPorProduto(_empresaAtiva, Produto)
                    .Where(q => q.VALORINICIAL >= deValor && q.VALORFINAL <= deValor && q.TIPOFAIXAPRECO == "V").ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível fazer usando o método [`Concat`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.concat?view=netframework-4.8) do LINQ.

```
var listaConcatenada = lista1.Concat(lista2);
```

[Veja funcionando no Repl.it](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/ptso415521)

Também é possível criar uma terceira lista e usar o método [`AddRange`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-6.0) para adicionar todos os itens das duas listas originais nesta terceira.

Neste caso, é importante inicializar a nova lista passando como [argumento do construtor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-ctor(system-int32)) a soma do tamanho das duas outras listas, desta forma a nova lista não terá um aumento de [capacidade](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.capacity?view=net-6.0) e, portanto, a operação é mais rápida porque não há copia de *arrays* internamente.

```cs
var novaLista = new List<Tipo>(lista1.Count + lista2.Count);
novaLista.AddRange(lista1);
novaLista.AddRange(lista2);
```

Comment: Observação: para funcionar, importe o namespace `using System.Linq;`.

Answer (score 3):

Use o [AddRange](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=netframework-4.8):

```
List<VW_PARCEIROSOFERTAS> bdofertas = new List<VW_PARCEIROSOFERTAS>();
bdofertas.AddRange(bdofertasPrazo);
bdofertas.AddRange(bdofertasValor);
```

> A coleção cujos elementos devem ser adicionados ao final do List. A
>   coleção em si não pode ser null, mas pode conter elementos que são
>   null, se o tipo T é um tipo de referência.

Comment: Uma boa ideia é instanciar a lista passando como parâmetro a quantidade de elementos que ela vai ter uma vez que esta informação é de fácil acesso. Dessa forma, você evita a criação de _arrays_ desnecessários internamente.